# Can Google Package App use external directories during packing?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am writing a number of Google Packaged Apps which run independently, but share lots of code.  For example, they all use "library.js".  I would like to have only one copy of library.js so any changes to it will be used by all newly packed apps.

To package my apps, it seems they all must have a copy of library.js in their own directory structure, whereas it would be nice to have a single master copy in some other directory that is accessible to all.  I currently do a manual check to make sure all files are up-to-date before packing, and I am writing some code to do the check automatically, but it seems like a work-around.

Can a Google Packaged App use JS code in external library directories, or must all code be under the root directory of the app (i.e., requiring copying from external directory) when packing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried providing a URL i.e. host the javscript file in .js format to an accessible location to your apps and then provide the .js file URL in all your apps code. The very next time you want to change, all you have to do is to update that .js file.

Comment: Tried it. "Not allowed to load local resource."

Comment: What was the problem with it to cause error? I am also interested